# Adjust number of discrete axis breaks based on window width in Shiny with ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, ggplotly

I have a dashboard that have a number of graphs (created in ggplot then converted into plotly plots with `ggplotly()` arranged in columns of two within `fluidRows()`:

[image: picture of discrete bar graph]

However, when the browser window is minimised, the bar sizes adjust automatically, but the x-axis labels become squashed together:

[image]

How can I dynamically adjust the number of x-axis breaks based on browser window width? I know I can get the dimensions of the browser window using code [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36995142/get-the-size-of-the-window-in-shiny), and I had the idea of creating a reactive value based on the window width that I could then pass to `breaks` in `scale_x_discrete()`, but I haven't been able to bring the entire thing together.

I need a solution that will work regardless of what discrete values are on the x-axis, since I have about ~20 different graphs with different values, e.g. some may be be 'Level1 - Level10', others may be different codes, e.g. AEF01 - AEF10.

Reproducible code:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(
  x = factor(rep(paste0("Level", 1:10)), 
             levels = c("Level1", "Level2", "Level3", "Level4", "Level5", "Level6",
                        "Level7", "Level8", "Level9", "Level10")),
  y = rep(runif(10, 20, 100))
)


ui <- fluidPage(

    fluidRow(
      column(
        width = 6,
        plotlyOutput("plot")
      )
    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot <- dat %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = y)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") 
    
    ggplotly(plot)
    
  })
}
```

Comment: I'd [rotate the labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39116470/rotate-labels-using-plotly-in-r).

Comment: That's not what I require.

Comment: I am aware of that. So I posted a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The example below shows a possible route. I created some JS functions to calculate % of overlap between the labels (you could also decide just to use the screen resolution for an easier approach) and pass that on to `shiny`.

The difficult part however, remains of how to translate this signal to a meaningful selection of breaks. I showed one solution, but it is not the most elegant one. Here, you need to define your own logic. But the example shows at least how to

1. Create a plot specific trigger which can be read by `shiny`: `<plot_id>_overlap`
2. Us this trigger to so *something* in the `renderPlot` function.

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(
  x = factor(rep(paste0("Level", 1:10)), 
             levels = c("Level1", "Level2", "Level3", "Level4", "Level5", "Level6",
                        "Level7", "Level8", "Level9", "Level10")),
  y = rep(runif(10, 20, 100))
)

ovlp_script <- HTML("function overlap_pct(a, b) {
   let dim_a = a.getBoundingClientRect();
   let dim_b = b.getBoundingClientRect();
   return Math.max(dim_a.x + dim_a.width - dim_b.x, 0) / (dim_b.x + dim_b.width);
}

function check_overlap(id) {
   let ticks = $('#' + id + ' .xtick text').toArray();
   let res = {sum_overlap: 0,
              elem: ticks[0]};
   ticks.shift();
   res = ticks.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return {sum_overlap: a.sum_overlap + overlap_pct(a.elem, b),
              elem: b};
   }, res);
   return res['sum_overlap'];
}
")

resize_listener <- HTML("var resizeId;
   function notify_resize() {
      $('.js-plotly-plot').each(function(idx, e) {
         let ovlp = check_overlap(e.id);
         Shiny.setInputValue(e.id + '_overlap', ovlp, {priority: 'event'});
      });
   }   
   
   $(window).resize(function() {
      clearTimeout(resizeId);
      resizeId = setTimeout(notify_resize, 750);
   });
")


ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(tags$script(ovlp_script, resize_listener)),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 6,
      plotlyOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    overlap <- input$plot_overlap
    ## ToDo: find a smarter way of how to translate overlap % into selection of levels
    overlap <- if (is.null(overlap)) 0 else 4 * overlap
    nl <- levels(dat$x)
    step_size <- length(nl) / floor(length(nl) * (1 - overlap))
    sel <- unique(round(seq(1L, length(nl), step_size)))
    plot <- dat %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = y)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
      scale_x_discrete(breaks = nl[sel])

    ggplotly(plot)
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```